# Convert webpage (html) to thumbnail/preview for output via PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linux, thumbnails

So i've done a lot of searching on here and Google and haven't seem to come across anything that is known to work or that I think will accomplish what i'm looking to do.

Basically right now i've been using www.thumboo.com to create thumbnails via their API however they do not support SSL and where im creating the preview is under a customer area where SSL is required.

So i'm looking to either develop something myself or find something already developed to use, i would like to create a simple "screenshot" or "thumbnail" of a website address on the fly, not sure if i want to cache it yet or not, but either way doesn't matter.

Does anybody know of any scripts out there that can accomplish this?  I'm not looking to get a screenshot of the "entire" page, just what a "browser" would originally see without scrolling down, just like how it works on www.thumboo.com.

I'm not too concerned with the scripting language but i plan on outputting the file using php by pulling the file from somewhere or activating the script with java or php.

Does anybody know of any other thumbnail services that may have an API That works with SSL or any scripts that are *still* developed for this purpose?  Everything i have found has been outdated which makes me wonder if there is some easy way to do it now with some type of function or module i may need to add to PHP.

I am server admin so i can customize PHP and the server as i need to get it to work.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Did you look into `wkhtmltoimage` yet?

Comment: Request an insecure page from your ssl page that in turn requests the thumbnail.

Comment: tried pulling another php script from my site to make it secure, but for some reason it won't process the image itself :(  i thought that would have done it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.thumbalizr.com/apitools.php
i have never use but seems like this  works for you.

Comment: i tried to use it but they like all the other ones i found online want you to pay to use their service....doh!